# Photoshop - how to mirror a path about an axis?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Let's say i have a photoshop path. I want to mirror it horizontally or vertically and connect the two paths together. How can i do this?

Comment: photoshop version?

Comment: CS4 Extended. ()

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Hold CTRL + alt key. Click and drag the path to get a duplicate.
2. Select one of the paths and go to Edit/Transform Path/Flip Vertical.
3. With your path tool selected hold down shift and click on the two paths. Up in the options bar click on combine.

Comment: http://www.photoshoplady.com/realistic-decorated-wine-bottle-illustration/
Shows how to duplicate half a bottle image and then merge the path.